# Increase element ID by one after every click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone multiple divs on my page by using the jQuery `.clone()` method. The problem is, as soon as a div is cloned, it needs to have a unique ID. The cloned ID has to be there too. I was thinking I could keep the old ID and then just add a number on, increasing as more div's are on the page.

Example: base ID = one, so div one would be `id`, then div two would be `id-2`, then div three would be `id-3`, etc.

Is this possible? My attempt at this is below:

```
$("a").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        var id = $(target).attr("id");
        $(target).clone().attr("id",id + $(id).size()).attr("class","drag").appendTo("body");
});
```

Each `a` tag looks like this:

```
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
```

Then the cloned element looks like this:

```
<div class="drag base" style="background-color:blue" id="one"></div>
<div class="drag base" style="background-color:green" id="two"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe some of these answers will help. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+clone+increment+ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/3tu7V/1/

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
            var target = $(this).attr("href");
            var id = $(target).attr("id"); 
            var click = $(target).data("clicked") || 0;
            $(target).data("clicked", ++click);            
            $(target).clone().attr("id",id + click).attr("class","drag").appendTo("body");

    });
});
​
```

I think this does what you want according to your comment:
"Ah, is there any way for the element ID to be reset when the base ID is unique? Ex.) "If you clone div "one", it will produce "one-1", then "one-2", but if you then clone div "two", it will produce "two-3", not "two-1""

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer:

You can use the jQuery [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to keep a track of the clones, and their counts:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var targetId = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); // "one", "two"
    var count = $("div[id^=" + targetId + "]").length; // initial value will be 1
    $("#" + targetId).clone().attr("id", targetId + '-' + count).attr("class", "drag").appendTo("body");
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WsLWj/1/)

Comment: The last element as in the last element cloned?

Comment: The last element would be the element with the highest id.

Comment: Ah, is there any way for the element ID to be reset when the base ID is unique? Ex.) "If you clone div "one", it will produce "one-1", then "one-2", but if you then clone div "two", it will produce "two-3", not "two-1""

Comment: The "one" and "two" are not hardcoded, the script will suffix a number to the current id (if there isn't one) or increment the number (if there is one). The catch here is that that the element being cloned must have the highest sequence -- otherwise you'll need some kind of counter.

Answer (score 1):

i think in ur case $(id).size() will always be = 2. (only the last one and its clone will have the same id)
why don't you use a global variable `var clickNumber` that you increment each time.
your code will be

```
var clickNumber = 0;    
$("a").click(function(){
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        var id = $(target).attr("id");
        clickNumber ++;
        $(target).clone().attr("id","id-" + clickNumber).attr("class","drag").appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: I like this example, but as you can see in my OP, I have more than one div. So, if you use this, and clone div "one", it will produce "one-1", then "one-2", but if you then clone div "two", it will produce "two-3", not "two-1".

Answer (score 1):

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SjtAE/)

```
var increment = 2;

$('a').live('click', function() {
    $(this).clone().attr('id','id-' + (increment++)).appendTo('body');
});​
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The same problem is happening with this that happened with Dany's example. If you use this and clone div "one", it will produce "one-1", then "one-2", but if you then clone div "two", it will produce "two-3", not "two-1"

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('a').addClass('link');
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).clone(true).attr('id', 'id-' + $('.link').length).appendTo('body');
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Em8PE/1/**